# How to use emojies in Avalonia textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, avaloniaui, avalonia

I developing chat desktop application and nned to display emojies in textbox and sended message like

[image: emoji thumb]

```
<TextBox Classes="input" 
Height="80" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
Padding="12 8 36 8" 
TextWrapping="Wrap" 
AcceptsReturn="True" 
BorderBrush="Transparent" 
Foreground="#040415" 
CaretBrush="#0091AE" 
Watermark="{x:Static resources:ResourcesStrings.SendMessage}"/>
```

I try to use many FontFamilies but always i see white squares with black border. In this style, i removed font family property

Comment: It looks like emoji support only got merged [less than a year and a half ago](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/4893#issuecomment-1029946099). Can you give details about the version of avalonia you're using?

Comment: 0.10.19, i think about update, thx

Comment: From what I can see, 0.10.19 is well newer than the PR I linked to, so I don't think its a versioning issue

Comment: Then what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Avalonia` version **11.0.0** it work fine. For more emojies need set `font family`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).